# Difference of quoted column names

Tags: sqlite, alter-table

I just added a new column to my `sqlite` database with following command:

```
ALTER TABLE foo_table ADD COLUMN fooCol TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT 'foo';
```

When I look at the dump, I get the following:

```
PRAGMA foreign_keys=OFF;
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
CREATE TABLE "foo_table" (
"ID" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
"barfoo" TEXT
, fooCol TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT 'bar');
```

And now I'm wondering, since my `fooCol` is not in quotes like `barfoo` and `ID`, if it has any further consequences or not. Otherwise I would have copy my whole database (with all the metadata, which, btw, I don't know how to do) and drop the old table.

Answer (score 0):

In SQLite, identifiers are never case sensitive, even when quoted.
(Quotes are used to avoid conflicts with SQL keywords.)

Comment: How likely are these conflicts to happen? Say my column has a somewhat standard name like `status`?

Comment: In an embedded database like SQLite, you are supposed to know what [the keywords](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html) of your particular version are. But this doesn't help you in, e.g., Android.